# Obtain the most used type for an id based on its views

Tags: sql, rank

I'm trying to get out the most viewed type from my SQL, am pretty new so I'm not sure which logic to use, between either RANK, COUNT and/or SUM.

So I have three columns: ID, seller_type, and view_count

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------+
| ID | Seller_type | view_count |  Week  |  Day  |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------+
| 33 | Vendor      |         54 | Week1  | Day 1 |
| 33 | Vendor      |         45 | Week1  | Day 2 |
| 33 | Marketplace |         68 | Week2  | Day 4 |
| 33 | Marketplace |         12 | Week2  | Day 2 |
| 32 | Vendor      |         93 | Week2  | Day 3 |
| 33 | Third-party |         74 | Week1  | Day 6 |
| 32 | Third-party |         10 | Week1  | Day 1 |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-------+
```

Basically I have a table in which there is an ID, a seller type and the number of views for an id. A unique ID can have more than one row with the same seller (as they can be different weeks/days). What I want to do is for example, calculate which seller_type has had the most views for ID 33 during week 1. In this case Vendor (54+45), and not Marketplace (12).

So my plan was to start using the SUM:

```
WITH A AS (
SELECT
ID
,Seller_type
,SUM(view_count) as Total_views
,Week

FROM Table_A

GROUP BY
ID
,Seller_type
,Week
)

SELECT
CASE WHEN Week = 'Week1' THEN MAX(Total_views)
CASE WHEN Week = 'Week2' THEN

FROM A
```

So I have the totals, for each seller for each ID in my subquery A, and I wanted use a CASE in my main query to indicate to select the max total_views' seller type. But I don't know how to write my CASE WHEN.

Any comments/indications will be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to basically want aggregation:

```
select seller_type, week, sum(view_count)
from t
group by seller_type, week;
```

Then you want some filtering and to choose the top one:

```
select seller_type, week, sum(view_count)
from table_a
where week = 'Week 1'
group by seller_type, week
order by sum(view_count)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Note that not all databases support the standard `fetch first` clause -- but all support the functionality in some say (say with `select top` or `limit`).

Answer (score 0):

If I get this right you want to get the seller type with the most views per week. You can use `rank()` or `row_number()` for that. With `rank()` you'll get all of the top records should there be more than one record with the same top view count. Replace `rank()` for `row_count()` to only (randomly) select one of the records in such a case.

```
WITH
a
...
SELECT id,
       seller_type,
       total_views,
       week
       FROM (SELECT id,
                    seller_type,
                    total_views,
                    week
                    rank() OVER (PARTITION BY week
                                 ORDER BY total_views DESC) r
                    FROM a)
       WHERE r = 1;
```